# Supervised GenServer not being restarted?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I've reduced the size of the question, cause it was too big. Here's the code:

```
defmodule MayRaiseGenServer do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    IO.puts "started MyServer, name is #{__MODULE__}"

    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def maybe_will_raise do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :maybe_will_raise)
  end

  def handle_call(:maybe_will_raise,_from, state) do
    IO.puts "maybe_will_raise called!"
    :random.seed(:erlang.now)
    number = Enum.to_list(1..100) |> Enum.shuffle |> List.first
    IO.puts "number is #{number}"
    if rem(number,2) != 0 do
      raise "#{number}"
    end
    {:reply, {"You got lucky"}, state}
  end
end

defmodule MayRaiseSupervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link([]) do
    IO.puts "starting supervisor, name is #{__MODULE__}"
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
  end

  def init(arg) do
    IO.puts "initted with arg: #{arg}"
    children = [
      worker(MayRaiseGenServer, [])
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one, restart: :transient, name: __MODULE__)
  end
end

MayRaiseSupervisor.start_link([])
IO.inspect MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise
:timer.sleep(2000)
IO.puts "after sleep"
```

Initially, I only saw the message for starting the GenServer once, but now I see it again. Here's the output:

```
starting supervisor, name is Elixir.MayRaiseSupervisor
initted with arg:
started MyServer, name is Elixir.MayRaiseGenServer
maybe_will_raise called!
number is 14
started MyServer, name is Elixir.MayRaiseGenServer

11:32:28.807 [error] GenServer MayRaiseGenServer terminating
** (RuntimeError) 14
    lib/mini.ex:20: MayRaiseGenServer.handle_call/3
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:615: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:647: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: :maybe_will_raise
State: []
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(MayRaiseGenServer, :maybe_will_raise, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (RuntimeError) 14
            lib/mini.ex:20: MayRaiseGenServer.handle_call/3
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:615: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:647: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:604: GenServer.call/3
    lib/mini.ex:45: (file)
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

From the above output, it's not very clear to me what happens. It looks like the GenServer is restarted, based on the message shown on IO, but why is the exception being thrown again? Also, in this code:

```
MayRaiseSupervisor.start_link([])
IO.inspect MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise
:timer.sleep(2000)
IO.puts "after sleep"
```

If the method call `MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise` will indeed raise an error, it looks like the lines after, the one with `timer.sleep` and the `IO.puts` won't be run anymore. Even if I change the code to try and handle the exception, like this:

```
MayRaiseSupervisor.start_link([])
try do
  IO.inspect MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise
rescue
  RuntimeError -> IO.puts "there was an error"
end
:timer.sleep(2000)
IO.puts "after sleep"
```

I still cannot seem to reach the last `IO.puts` ( if there was an error ). Is there a way of handling the call to `maybe_will_raise` that would allow me to handle it raising an error, and continuing execution? I'm guessing supervisors won't automatically retry a piece of code when they're being restarted.

Comment: Well, according to the output the server was restarted as there are 2 lines with `started MyServer`. You can also check that by invoking: `Process.alive? Process.whereis(MayRaiseGenServer)`. If your server is running it will return true.

Comment: I noticed the different PIDs, but shouldn't the `IO.puts "started MyServer"` output appear again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As my point of view.

Your output above is telling you a stack trace when an exception was raised with an exit signal in `GenServer.call(MayRaiseGenServer, :maybe_will_raise, 5000)` and an error log because `terminate/2` is invoked with a reason `{%RuntimeError{message: ...}, [...]`.

You can define `terminate/2` callback to see:

```
def terminate(reason, _state) do
  IO.inspect reason
end
```

[Terminate/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html#c:terminate/2)

> If reason is not :normal, :shutdown nor {:shutdown, term} an error is
>   logged.

But when an exception was raised inside a GenServer callback (except `init/1`) it will invoke `terminate/2` that telling the server is about to exit (Exit signal was sent).

So code after this line will not be executed:

```
try do
IO.inspect MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise
...
```

> but shouldn't the IO.puts "started MyServer" output appear again?

And also when your GenServer is exited.Your supervisor will start a new one linking the main process with your GenServer process (Your `MayRaiseGenServer.start_link` got call again)

The last thing is if you want to make the code continue executing.You can catch **exit signal** like this:

```
MayRaiseSupervisor.start_link([])
try do
  IO.inspect MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise
catch
  :exit, _ -> IO.puts "there was an error"
end
:timer.sleep(2000)
IO.puts "after sleep"
```

But i think you should consider of using `raise` in your GenServer callback.Hope that help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your Supervisor is not linked to the the GenServer. Therefore it is not notified about death of the child (through an exit signal). To fix that, you need to use `GenServer.start_link/3`.

For more information check either [Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html) or [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html) documentation on processes.

Comment: I've updated the description. I seem to get the same behaviour also when using `start_link`

Answer (score 0):

By mistake, I have used `GenServer.start` instead of `GenServer.start_link` and searched for answer for two days.

**Note 1:** Supervisor tree in `:observer.start` helped a lot to debug this problem

**Note 2:** But above problem using `start_link` only. I am writing for people who are doing the same mistake like me :-P.

Answer (score 0):

The server is being restarted. To prove it, I added this snippet

```
spawn fn ->
  :timer.sleep(1000)
  IO.inspect GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :maybe_will_raise)
end
```

in two places. One in handle_call callback and I also added it in the init function. Here is the complete module after that

```
  defmodule MayRaiseGenServer do
    @moduledoc false

    use GenServer

    def start_link do
      IO.puts "started MyServer, name is #{__MODULE__}"

      GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
    end

    def init(_) do
      spawn fn ->
        :timer.sleep(1000)
        IO.inspect GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :maybe_will_raise)
      end
      {:ok, nil}
    end

    def maybe_will_raise do
      GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :maybe_will_raise)
    end

    def handle_call(:maybe_will_raise,_from, state) do
      IO.puts "maybe_will_raise called!"
      :random.seed(:erlang.now)
      number = Enum.to_list(1..100) |> Enum.shuffle |> List.first
      IO.puts "number is #{number}"
      if rem(number,2) != 0 do
        raise "#{number}"
      end
      spawn fn ->
        :timer.sleep(1000)
        IO.inspect GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :maybe_will_raise)
      end
      {:reply, {"You got lucky"}, state}
    end


  end
```

Then you do not have to call

```
IO.inspect MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise
```

After

```
MayRaiseSupervisor.start_link([])
```

Try it and see